# Vue.js trigger function each time a specific element is appended

Tags: javascript

How can I trigger a function each time my `<canvas>` element is (re)appended in Vue.js?

Template:

```
<div class="article" v-if="displayArticle">
    [...]
    <div v-if="sample">
        <canvas></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want a specific function to be triggered each time the canvas element is removed and then reappended from the DOM, for example when the `sample` variable is set to *false* and then to *true*, I want to call a specific function that will draw something on the canvas.

Comment: Create a watcher on `sample` then.

Comment: @connexo could you please provide an example for that?

Comment: Done. Check my answer and the documentation link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a watcher on `sample`. Example:

```
export default {
  el: '#yourEl',
  data() {
    return {
      sample: false,
      /* other vm data properties */
    }
  },
  watch: {
    sample(newVal, oldVal) {
      /* code that is executed whenever sample changes 
         the current value of sample gets passed in newVal, 
         the value it had before the change occurred comes in as oldVal
      */
    }
  }
}
```

A watcher is simply a named function inside the `watch` property of your `Vue` instance. By convention it uses the same name as the watched property.

Reference:

> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

Comment: thanks. Is the watcher called even if `displayArticle` value is edited/inversed?

Comment: No. Dependencies resulting from DOM structure are not taken into consideration. You could still do a watcher on either, and also a computed property `canvasVisible` like `canvasVisible() { return this.displayArticle && this.sample }`.